# Resize canvas element/shape

Tags: jquery, html, canvas, resize

I basically am in the process of creating a small script that will allow you to upload an image, mark somewhere on the image with a yellow box and then save the image. I am using HTML5 canvas for this. I have everything in place, uploading images and adding the shape to it, but now I've figured with the various sizes of images that will be uploaded, I need the 'shape' (yellow rectangle) to be able to be resized. I have a slider that outputs 2 numbers (width and height) when they are dropped somewhere along the slider. This calls onSizeChange:

```
    function onSizeChange(x2,y2) {
        context.clearRect(<?php echo $xcoord;?>, <?php echo $ycoord;?>, 30, 30);
        context.beginPath();
        context.rect(<?php echo $xcoord;?>, <?php echo $ycoord;?>, x2, y2);
        context.fillStyle = 'yellow';
        context.fill();
        context.lineWidth = 2;
        context.strokeStyle = 'black';
        context.stroke();
}
```

This sort of has the desired effect, but it removes the chunk of background image too (not just the yellow rectangle) and also it will only resize from 30,30 (that's the bit it clears out, and is the original auto rectangle size).

I'm struggling to do this, I've even tried clearing the whole canvas and redrawing from scratch but even facing issues with that, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the initial yellow box size based on an arbitrary size. When then an image is loaded use this arbitrary size to create a scale factor.

For example:

```
// lets say the yellow box' size is relative to:
var bWidth = 800,         // our "calibration" size.
    bHeight = 600,
    initialWidth = 50,    // size of yellow box relative
    initialHeight = 50;   // to "calibration" size.
```

Load in an image and calculate scaling factors:

```
var scaleX = image.width / bWidth;
var scaleY = image.height / bHeight;
```

Now simply multiply scaleX/Y with the initial box size:

```
var newWidth = initialWidth * scaleX;
var newHeight = initialHeight * scaleY;
```

Comment: 2 Birds - One stone. Don't know why I didn't think of this, thanks a lot for a great answer! :)

Comment: @JordanBarker no problem :-) Good luck with your project!